# Gunicorn with Flask using wrong Python

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to bootstrap a Flask app on a Gunicorn server. By putting the two tools' docs together, plus searching around on SO, this is what I have so far... but it's not quite working.

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**what I ran**:

From the same directory as app.py,

```
gunicorn app:app
```

Even starting this small, I've missed something. The error message is not very helpful:

> 2013-09-12 20:13:07 [11461] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.5
>   2013-09-12 20:13:07 [11461] [INFO] Listening at: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` (11461)
>   2013-09-12 20:13:07 [11461] [INFO] Using worker: sync
>   2013-09-12 20:13:07 [11528] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11528
>   2013-09-12 20:13:07 [11528] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11528)
>   2013-09-12 20:13:08 [11461] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
>   2013-09-12 20:13:08 [11461] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

By the way, I'm running this on a Debian Linux system. Many thanks in advance for your help!

**Update**

After turning on debugging, I got some more instructive error messages. This has become a very specific problem very fast: `ImportError: No module named flask`. Usually I get this sort of error when I'm not using my virtualenv--but I am. And upon closer inspection, Gunicorn seems to be using a different version of Python than my virtualenv uses, that is Python3. So... my particular python seems not to be getting used. How do I fix this, and tell Gunicorn to use the right Python?

Comment: How did you install gunicorn?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gunicorn`, if I recall.

Comment: Ah, can you try installing it into your virtualenv? It's probably loading gunicorn from the system path. Just `pip install gunicorn`.

Comment: Sure, I'll try that. Hold on.

Comment: The suspense is killing me Brian

Comment: Please refer to comments on this answer to learn how it ended, haha :D : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776917/1151229 @elPastor

Comment: @BrianPeterson - I can sleep now!  Thank you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The gunicorn utility may be running out of the system path rather than your virtualenv.

Make sure to `pip install gunicorn` into the virtualenv.

Here's the pip freeze of a virtualenv I setup to run your app:

```
(so_2)20:38:25 ~/code/tmp/flask_so$ pip freeze
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
SQLAlchemy==0.8.2
Werkzeug==0.9.4
gunicorn==18.0
itsdangerous==0.23
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

In reality, I only ran these `pip install`s:

```
$ pip install flask
$ pip install gunicorn
$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: Sorry, I kind of redacted my app.py to just show you the basic functionality I was trying to get. Somehow left out the import for SqlAlchemy.

Comment: But, hmm, OK. I think I will try to pip install gunicorn (as the commenter above suggests).

Comment: Oh ok. I'll trim my answer to just have the bit about gunicorn being in the virtualenv rather than the system path. Since I was the commenter, my feelings won't be hurt. ;)

Comment: Ah, got it working! I `apt-get remove`d gunicorn globally, `pip install`ed it in my virtualenv, restarted the virtualenv, and it worked like a charm. Thanks much.

Comment: Yay! Internet high-fives!

Answer (score 33):

I have the same problem as You.
The problem is that gunicorn for some reason load the enviroment outside your virtual env. I solved by uninstalling the package gunicorn outside virtual enviroment;

```
(env) $ deactivate
$ sudo pip uninstall gunicorn
```

So you come back to your env and try to run. In my case env folder I typed:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install gunicorn
(env) $ gunicorn server:app
2013-10-19 20:40:56 [11923] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-10-19 20:40:56 [11923] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (11923)
2013-10-19 20:40:56 [11923] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-10-19 20:40:56 [11926] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11926
```

Comment: This is basically what I came to as well--installing gunicorn globally made it not behave well inside the virtualenv.

Comment: This solves the issue. Gunicorn for some unknown reasons loads the gloab env and not the Venv.

Answer (score 8):

Gunicorn may be installed at multiple location in your system. It may be present in

1. OS default Python Path
2. Anaconda Python Path

By default when you specify

> gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 flaskApp:app

You are referrng to operating system's default Python where in the same path flask package is not installed results in error.
Better specify which gunicorn you are reffering to by providing proper path to gunicorn

> **/home/sunil/anaconda2/bin/gunicorn** -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 flaskApp:app

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your virtual environment is called `env` and your app is called `app` and gunicorn was install properly.You may try:

```
sudo env/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5432 wsgi:app
```

This force the app to use the gunicron in your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new env. and freshly installed the dependency, it worked for me.
Also, I am using miniconda to manage my env.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which flask is been used(base/<your_env>) using `which flask` or `which gunicorn`. If it is base you need to uninstall from base env, then re-install in <your_env>. Also you can force installation in <your_env > using `pip install -I flask gunicorn`.